# Display Custom Posts

Tags: customization

I have created custom posts with the name "review". From WP admin i can create these custom posts. But to display them at user side i am facing a problem. As i am developing plugin i don't want create a template in theme. This is code i used to display the custom posts. But it is showing 404 template.

```
function review_template_function($template_path){
global $post;
if(get_query_var('post_type') == 'review'){
    if(is_single()){
        if(file_exists(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'review-preview.php')){
            $template_path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'review-preview.php';
        }else{
            $template_path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'review-preview.php';
        }
    }
}
return $template_path;
}
  add_filter('template_include','review_template_function');
```

Answer (score 0):

`plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'review-preview.php'`  //this is the culprit!!

Above line works for PHP code on a plugin directory file. But the function I assume is in functions.php file of your theme directory. So you may have to give full directory path in your code like:

`/home/user/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/review-preview.php`

Comment: Shouldn't he also be able to pass the name of the plugin file: `plugin_dir_path(<plugin_filename>).'review-preview.php'`

Comment: @KristerAndersson I don't think it will work because plugins path is different to theme path.

Comment: It will work as long as he supplies the name of the  plugin file.